# how to add the rows to the datatable while executereader reads the rows from the table?

Tags: c#, .net, datarow

I want to add the rows that are read by executereader to the new datatable with C# coding

Comment: @Saurabh: No, that link is not to his question but to your answer (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many unknowns in your question. Foreg, is the data table typed or untyped? What are the column types? And so forth.

But anyway, here's a general example. I adapted the code from the original sample given [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx)

private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString =
        "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";

```
using (SqlConnection connection =
           new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command =
        new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    // Call Read before accessing data.
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       CustomersRow newCustomersRow = Customers.NewCustomersRow();

       newCustomersRow.CustomerID = reader[0].ToString();
       newCustomersRow.CompanyName = reader[1].ToString();
       dt.Rows.Add(newCustomersRow);
    }

    // Call Close when done reading.
    reader.Close();
}
```

}

Comment: "There are too many unknowns in your question" - then why bother with an answer? We shouldn't encourage questions like this.

Comment: I understand that but there are times when an answer is urgently required and one may not have the time to elaborate. Hence, am just trying to help out.

Answer (score 1):

Make a dataTable oject with the columns same as that of the datareader. Pls have a look at the code below.

Eg:

```
DataTable _dt=new DataTable();//public 

void AddColumns()
{
 _dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)));
 _dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("mark", typeof(int)));
}
```

So in your datatable u have two columns[ID and mark].

retriving data

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader rd=cmd.Execute
Reader();
```

Write a function to add New Row

```
public void NewRow(DataReader rd)
{
   while(rd.Read())
    {
   DataRow dr=_dt.NewRow();
   dr["ID"]=Convert.toInt32(rd["ID"]);
   dr["Mark"]=Convert.toInt32(rd["Mark"]);
   _dt.Rows.Add(dr)
      }
}
```

This way u can able to add values to dataTable.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the .NewRow function to create a row based on the same schema so thanks for that!